# Create "denser" np.linspace with same points as original np.linspace

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linspace

I have a `base` array of equally spaced values `[0, 1, ..., 511]`. I need to create a `target` array over `[0 to 511]` that consists of approximately 4096 values. It must **also** contain all the values `0, 1, 2, ...` that are in `base`.

```
base = [0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 511]

target = [0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0.875, 1, ..., 511]
```

I have:

```py
base = np.linspace(0, 511, 512)

target = np.linspace(0, 511, 4096)
```

Unfortunately, `target` seems to be incorrect:

```
[0;0.124786;0.249573;0.374359;0.499145;0.623932;0.748718;0.873504;0.998291;...]
```

I need it to contain the numbers from `base`.

Answer (score 0):

To construct an equally spaced sequence `(0, ..., b)` containing all integers within that interval, where `b` is an integer, choose any integer `k` and then:

```
np.linspace(0, b, k * b + 1)
```

In your case,

```
np.linspace(0, 511, 8 * 511 + 1)
```

Comment: Thank your for the answer. This indeed does contain all the values, however, it's only 4089 values. I need it to be 4096 and seems to me that's not possible, is it?

Comment: Unfortunately not, if you want to maintain the property of "evenly spaced". Is 4096 necessary for a reason?

Comment: Yes. I do signal processing where I need to shift oversampled data and later I need to resample, again, down to 512 again.

Now that alone is no reason, but certain sample positions within the 4096 space also contain important information so I need to stay in that count. 
Can you tell me why it's not possible? I jus can't figure out the math...

Comment: "Proof": There is **exactly one** evenly spaced sequence between `[0, 511]` with 4096 elements. (Any other sequence is not evenly spaced.) This sequence can be generated by `np.linspace(0, 511, 4096)`. As you showed, the sequence that code generates is not desirable. By uniqueness, no other sequences exist, and thus the task is impossible.

Comment: On what domain did you sample the 4096 samples? Can you use that domain? If you use any other domain, it will require resampling.